# With $f(x) =xe^{-x}$ and $a_1\ldots a_N$ positive, show $\frac 1N \sum_{k=1}^Nf(a_k) \le \frac 1e$

Tags: calculus, inequality, summation

**Question**
Let $f(x)=xe^{-x} $. Given positive numbers $a_1 ... a_N$ show that:
$$\frac 1N \sum_{k=1}^Nf(a_k) \le \frac 1e$$

**Thoughts**

Using Cesàro's theorem on convergence of means I managed to show that close to the limit, the inequality is true (because $ne^{-n} \to 0 $) , but I've later noticed that I'm not being asked on the limit. What can be done to prove this for every area?

Comment: Sufficient to show that $f(x) < 1/e$ for $x>0$.

Comment: To apply Cesaro, shouldn't you assume something on the sequence $(a_k)$ (e.g, that it goes to $\infty$?)

Comment: Hint: $\sup=\max_{x\in\mathbb{R}} f(x)=f(1)=e^{-1}$ by simple study of the sign of $f'(x)=(1-x)e^{-x}$. So yo don't even need the $a_k$'s to be positive.

Answer (score 1):

For $x\ge 0$ we have: 
$$\log(x)\le x-1$$
$$x \le e^{x-1}$$
$$x e^{-x} \le e^{-1}$$

Then $f(a_k) \le \frac{1}{e}$ and so is the average.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple calculus techniques to show that the maximum of $f(x)$ occurs when $x=1$ and $f(1)=\frac{1}{e}$. The result then easily follows.